# VueJS Accessing an "export default{ }" internally vs. a defined constant main app

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have the following code in my main application page and if you use VueJS (which I'm starting to) this is probably familiar:

```
//written in ES6
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: function(){ return {
    query: {},
    requests: [],
    original: {},
    assignees: {},
    transiting: false,
    editing: false,
}},
created: function () {
    console.log(this.requests);   //this works
    console.log(app.requests);    //this also works
    this.doSomething('bar');
},
methods: {
    doSomething: function(arg){
        console.log('foo is a '+arg); //this works too
    }
}
});
```

BUT, my component JavaScript looks like this.  The `created` is running - I've checked - but I can't seem to access my data and methods the same way, mostly because I'm not familiar with "export default{ }"

```
export default {
    name: 'request-tracking-calendar',
    data: {
            events: [
                {
                    id: 10,
                    name: 'Boris',
                    ssn: '515860000',
                },
                {
                    id: 11,
                    name: 'Natasha',
                    ssn: '575860001',
                },
            ]
    },
    created: function(){
        console.log('Updating events dynamically..'); 
        {
            //code omitted for clarity
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // etc.
            xhr.onload = function(a) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    for (var i in xhr.response.data){
                    //DOESN'T work! not a function

      console.log(this.convertJSONToEvent(xhr.response.data[i])); 
                    }
                    console.log(this.events); //DOESN'T work
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        convertJSONToEvent(o){
            //do something to o..
            console.log('o was modified');
            return o;
        },
```

How would I get the above calls in second example to work here?  I.e. how would I access data and methods? Can a both declare a variable and "export default" at the same time so the exported default can reference itself?

Comment: `data` must be a function . Consult : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: sorry, got in a hurry to simplify - so bonus information, and I edited, but how to reference methods internally, esp. in the `created` section? (And now especially, how to access and set nodes in data()?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrow function `xhr.onload = (a)=>{}` to fix this.

normal function `function(){}` bind its own `this` context, so `this` won't be referring to the Vue component instance anymore

arrow function does not have its own `this`, so `this` will be inherited from the component automatically.

If you don't want to use arrow function *(because it's not supported in some browser)*, you could save `this` in a variable first and then use it in the function.

```
var _this = this;
xhr.onload = function(a) {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    for (var i in xhr.response.data) {
      // use _this
      console.log(_this.convertJSONToEvent(xhr.response.data[i]));
    }
    console.log(_this.events); // use _this
  }
};
```

Comment: This is ES6 transpiled to ES5.  Thank you for reminding me of this feature, and I hate using `var _this = this;` (sure you do too).  It worked.  But when I overzealously tried to change `created: function() {` to `created: () => {`, it didn't recognize this.convertJSONToEvent anymore.  Why?  And also, how would I set a value in data?

Comment: @OliverWilliams this can be fixed by changing `created: () => {` to `created() {` or `created: function(){`. This is due to the `this` context again. Because if you use arrow function in created hook, you will be referring to the `this` outside the component definition. Arrow function is useful but shouldn't be used all the time.

Comment: you may see the warning in https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: I see, that relates to your previous comment.  I've used `created` to SET a value or array in `data` for the main Vue instance, but how do I do the same thing in a component?

Comment: you can do the same thing in a component. setting the data of the component in created hook.